# jQuery, how to preload images and be notified when images are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am still new to all the Javascript stuffs and i have to be honest that i have not yet experimented anything concerning my question.

I would like to know if there is a way or a plugin with jQuery to preloaded multiples images and call a function when the images are loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preload images using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506825/preload-images-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `load` event for images, but they have a number of cross browser issues (it depends on what platforms you're targeting).

```
var allImgs = $("#container img").filter(function() { return ! this.complete; });
var allImgsLength = allImgs.length;

allImgs.on("load", function() {
    if (--allImgsLength) {
        // Images have loaded.
    }
});
```

If you don't mind including a plugin, there is [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages), (disclaimer: written by me) which handles this relatively nicely. :)

You'd use it like...

```
$("#container").waitForImages(function() {
    // Images have loaded.
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery at all, you can adapt the first example. If you're only targeting modern browsers...

```
var allImgs = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("#container img"), 
                             function(img) {
                                return ! img.complete;
                             });
var allImgsLength = allImgs.length;

[].forEach.call(allImgs, function(img) {
    img.addEventListener(function() {
        if (--allImgsLength) {
            // Images have loaded.
        }
    });
});
```

If you had to support old browsers...

```
var allImgs = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("img");
var allImgsLength = allImgs.length;
var i;
var eventCallback = function() {
                        if (--allImgsLength) {
                             // Images have loaded.
                        }
                    };

for (i = 0; i < allImgsLength; i++) {
    if (allImgs[i].complete) {
        allImgsLength--;
    }

    if (allImgs[i].addEventListener) {
        allImgs[i].addEventListener("load", eventCallback);
    } elseif (allImgs[i].attachEvent) {
        allImgs[i].attachEvent("onload", eventCallback);
    } else {
        allImgs[i].onload = eventCallback;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, with your plugin, if i understand correctly, i could create an invisible div container, put some images in it, and when they are all loaded i'll be able to retrieve the image independently from the div and place them in multiples different containers the way i want? And the images would already be loaded?

Comment: @Armz Yes, you could do that. It's not strictly what the plugin was designed for, but I've done that in the past with success.